# Resteasy Content-Type defaults

Tags: java, http-headers, resteasy

I'm writing an app using Resteasy that can return both JSON and XML, but at a choice will default to XML. Here's my method:

```
@GET
@Path("/content")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public String contentListRequestXml(@Context HttpServletRequest req, 
    @Context HttpServletResponse response, @Context UriInfo info, @Context HttpHeaders h) {
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    if(isXml)        
        return generateXML();
    else
        return generateJSON();
}
```

The problem that I have is that it is returning two Content-Types:

```
$ curl http://localhost:1234/content -i -H "Accept: application/json,application/xml" -I HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.25)
```

How do I stop resteasy from setting the second Content-Type, or is there a better way to do this without having to have two separate functions on the same @Path but with different @Produces annotations?

The other option is to not bother with the response.setContentType and have @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) and let Resteasy deal with it, but how do I detect the matched mediatype that will be returned? I can get the HttpHeaders object and call getAcceptableMediaTypes() on it, but this means I have to effectively re-interpret the Accept Header that resteasy has already done for me. Surely there must be a way of getting the returned MediaType from resteasy when you supply multiple @Produces parameters?

Comment: The other thing that I could do is to not bother with the response object and just have @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})

Answer (score 3):

Reading the @Produces section of this page http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features, it appears that the spec wants the app to choose whichever content type matches the HTTP Accept header. And if all of the content types in the `@Produces` annotation match, it should just use the first one.

So I'm thinking one of two things. It's possible that Resteasy doesn't properly implement the spec. It's also possible that the `@Produces` annotation and the `.setContentType` call aren't playing nice. I'm not a JAX-RS master, but I thought that the Produces annotation was there so that you don't have to directly interact with `Response` objects.

Comment: Oh, I should also mention that I get the same result if I totally get rid of the @Produces line. :-(

Comment: So... if your function returns a String, what are you doing with the Response object? If you're just returning a string that the response object contains, and you don't specify contenttype anywhere, resteasy might just be copying whatever's in the http accept. I would try returning a string AND using the @Produces line or not using the @Produces line and returning a Response.